# Error:(126, 13) Failed to resolve: com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox

I am using opentok library that is

```
    compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+'
```

and in my build.gradle file i have added

```
     maven {
        url  "http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven"
    }
```

but unable to solve this error

```
    Error:(126, 13) Failed to resolve: com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+
    Show in File
    Show in Project Structure dialog
```

And when i am trying to clean the project then i am getting this

```
    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration        ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
    > Could not resolve com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+.
    Required by:
     project :app
  > Could not resolve com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+.
     > Failed to list versions for com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk.
        > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/opentok/android/opentok-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
           > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/opentok/android/opentok-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
              > Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
  > Could not resolve com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+.
     > Failed to list versions for com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk.
        > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven/com/opentok/android/opentok-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
           > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven/com/opentok/android/opentok-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
              > Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
  > Could not resolve com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.9.+.
     > Failed to list versions for com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk.
        > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/com/opentok/android/opentok-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
           > Could not GET 'http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/com/opentok/android/opentok-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
              > Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
```

please help me to solve this, Thank you.

Comment: i have modified the version of opentok-android-sdk to 2.10.+, but didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

use `mavenCentral()` instead of `maven { url  "http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven" }`

Comment: Work like a charm for build error Could not HEAD 'http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.31/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.31.pom'

Answer (score -1):

I solved this error by following these steps:

- Go to File>New>New Module
- Select "Import .JAR/.AAR Package" and click next.
- Enter the path to .aar file and click finish.
- Go to File>Project Structure (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
- Under "Modules," in left menu, select "app."
- Go to "Dependencies tab.
- Click the green "+" in the upper right corner.
- Select "Module Dependency"
- Select the new module from the list.

please put the dependency version same as .aar file.